# AWS CodePipeline Assets

Tags: aws-codepipeline

In AWS CodePipeline every pipeline comes with the "stages" `Source`, `Build`, `UpdatePipeline` and `Assets`, which are provided by the framework.

What exactly is the purpose of the stage called `Assets` in this case?

Are contents of these file sets referenced in the `Assets` stage relevant for the current pipeline execution only, or are they relevant for subsequent pipeline executions, too?

Answer (score 0):

Can you point me to the URL that outlines those stages?  Been working with Codepipeline for two years and the stages supported by Amazon are as follows:

The following are the valid action categories in CodePipeline:

1. Source
2. Build
3. Test
4. Deploy
5. Approval
6. Invoke

[URL Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/reference-pipeline-structure.html)

What might be happening and i must just speculating, is that someone named your stages a specific name for the pipeline.  We need to see the buildspec to tell you what they do.  If you can share that we can provide better guidance also the reference links to those stages you are referring to.